# Fatal error: Cannot access protected property EE_Output::$parse_exec_vars in EE2

Tags: php, expressionengine

What does this error mean in 'expression engine 2'? I get it when I try to access
`http://localhost/alias/blog/admin.php`.

```
Fatal error: Cannot access protected property EE_Output::$parse_exec_vars in C:\web\blog\system\expressionengine\libraries\Core.php on line 423
```

If I comment out the line 423 it loads the control panel but none of the menu seems to work.

Comment: Has this install of EE been modified in any way? `output->parse_exec_vars` is not a protected property in a default EE install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using class `EE_Output` and try to use the value of `parse_exec_vars`.

But, because this is a **protected proterty**, it can only be accessed in the `EE_Output` class itself and **derived classes**.

You have not show any code, so I cannot go into detail, but this should get you going.